# The Clifford hierarchy and $ e^{2 \pi i/2^k} $

Tags: mathematics, clifford-group, clifford-hierarchy

Could someone give me an example of a gate in the Clifford hierarchy which cannot be written as
$$
e^{i \theta} V
$$
for some unitary $ V $ with entries in terms of $ \zeta_{2^k} $?

If no such example comes to mind, perhaps it is true that every gate in the $ k-1 $ level of the Clifford hierarch be written as a global phase times a determinant $ 1 $ matrix with entries in the cyclotomic field
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^k})
$$
where $ \zeta_{2^k}=e^{2\pi i/2^k} $ is a primitive $ 2^k $ root of unity?

Note that the claim is true for the first level of the hierarchy since the Pauli group is all global phase times determinant $ 1 $ matrices with entries from $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_4=i) $.

And the claim is true for second level of the hierarchy because the Clifford group is all global phase times determinant $ 1 $ matrices with entries from $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}) $. Determinant $ 1 $ Hadamard is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and determinant 1 phase gate is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline{\zeta_8} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta_8
\end{bmatrix}
$$
note that $\overline{\zeta_8}=\zeta_8^7 $ and $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\zeta_8+\zeta_8^7}{2} $ and $ i=\zeta_8^2 $

Maybe someone knows a gate from the third level of the Clifford hierarchy that cannot be written in terms of $ \zeta_{16} $?

Comment: I am confused, isn't that already answered by a combination of your previous questions?

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich Ok I think the part I was really confused about was whether all transversal gates of stabilizer codes are in the Clifford hierarchy. I've updated by question to reflect that.

Comment: "We use the disjointness to show that all transversal logical operators on stabilizer codes must be in the Clifford hierarchy, as conjectured by Zeng et al." Jochym-O'Connor, Kubica, Yodor: https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.021047

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich Thanks! I thought that fact was known but really started to doubt myself the other day. That's exactly the reference I wanted. Given that that part is established I'm now focusing on the second half of my original question: Is the Clifford hierarchy all defined over $ \zeta_{2^k} $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: Yes (assuming the generalized semi-Clifford conjecture is true)

Conjecture 2 of https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.2084 is that for any number of qubits $ n $ all elements of all levels $ k $ of the Clifford hierarchy are "generalized semi-clifford gates" meaning that they can be expressed as
$$
UPDV
$$
where $ U,V $ are Clifford , $ P $ is a permutation matrix, and $ D $ is a diagonal gate from the $ k $th level of the Clifford hierarchy.

Recall that the Clifford group is defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8) $, permutation matrices are defined over anything, and the structure of the diagonal gates in the Clifford hierarchy is well known, in particular the diagonal gates in the $ k $th level are generated by all $ C^iZ^{1/2^j} $[https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.11923] gates where $ i+j=k-1 $ and so diagonal gates are defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^{k+1}}) $. So all generalized semi Cliffords of level $ k $ are defined over $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^{k+1}}) $. Assuming the generalized semi Clifford conjecture then everything in the Clifford hierarchy is generalized semi Clifford and thus is defined over some $ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{2^{k+1}}) $.

Comment: I believe this answer is correct but I wanted to point out a slight subtlety. While the structure of diagonal gates in the Clifford Hierarchy is known, it does not (necessarily) imply that the diagonal gates, $D$, in $UPDV$ above must be restricted in exactly the same manner for all generalized semi-Clifford gates. It turns out you can prove that a gate $UPDV$ is in the Clifford Hierarchy iff elements P and D are individually in the Clifford Hierarchy. While expected, I could not find proof of it anywhere. I included a proof in appendix A of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.05398).